# Lotka Volterra with alternate resource

Tags: calculus, stability-in-odes

Say we have a variation of the Lotka Volterra system:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = ax-bxy-cx^2$

$\frac{dy}{dt} = ny+mxy-py^2$

where $a,b,c,m,n,p$ are positive constants and $x_0$ and $y_0$ represent the initial population. The values of $a,b,c,m,n,p,x_0,y_0$ don't matter as we can experiment with different ones.

I'm having trouble finding the equilibrium points and their stability. Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the critical points, we want $x' = 0, y' = 0$, so have:

$$ \dfrac{dx}{dt} = ax-bxy-cx^2 = 0 \\ \dfrac{dy}{dt} = ny+mxy-py^2 = 0 $$

We can write this as:

$$x(a-cx -by) = 0 \\ y(n + mx -py) = 0 $$

It is clear that we satisfy these equations with $x = 0, y = 0$.

If we choose $x = 0$ in the first equation, the second gives us:

$$ y = \dfrac{n}{p}$$

If we choose $y = 0$ in the second equation, the first gives us:

$$ x = \dfrac{a}{c}$$

Lastly, we are left analyzing the cases:

$$a-cx -by = 0 \\ n + mx -py = 0 $$

Using your favorite method for a $2x2$ (RREF), this simultaneously gives:

$$ x = \dfrac{a p-b n}{b m+c p}, y = \dfrac{a m+c n}{b m+c p}$$

We are left with four critical points to investigate as:

$$(x, y) = (0, 0), \left(0 , \dfrac{n}{p}\right), \left(\dfrac{a}{c} , 0 \right), \left(\dfrac{a p-b n}{b m+c p}, \dfrac{a m+c n}{b m+c p}\right)$$

It is obvious that some of the constants cannot be zero for obvious reasons, for example, $p \ne 0$ in the second critical point.

You can test these critical points in the original system to verify they simultaneously produce $x ' = 0, y' = 0$.

Next, start analyzing these points for stability (your turn).